# Is there a way to sort Google Sheets Tabs the last part of the tab name?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've inherited a Google Sheets file that has to be updated each month.  Each new tab is named mmm yyyy (January 2021, February 2021, etc.).  The problem is that there are tabs spanning 3+ years and the new tabs are always at the back.  Is there a way to sort these tabs by year (high to low) then month?  I've found the below coding to alphabetize the tabs, but that doesn't quite get me my desired result.

```
function sortSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetNameArray = [];
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheetNameArray.push(sheets[i].getName());
  }

  sheetNameArray.sort();

  for (var j = 0; j < sheets.length; j++) {
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameArray[j]));
    ss.moveActiveSheet(j + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: I would strongly advised you consider to ditch the ridiculous archaic month-leading naming and use the international ISO date format (yyyy-mm-dd) as tab names. You can rename all tabs just once (manually or with script) and forget the headache forever. This is the perfect example why everyone should use ISO date format whenever there is no very good reasons against of it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Arranging Sheets

This sorts the sheet names, reverses the order and then arranges them in that sort order.

```
function arrangeSheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let shts = ss.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getName());
  shts.sort().reverse();//Sorting by names
  shts.forEach((name,i) =>{
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(name));
    ss.moveActiveSheet(i + 1);
  });
}
```

I gather that you can already sort the sheet names in the order that you want.

If not then try this:

```
function arrangeSheets() {
  const mA = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let shts = ss.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getName());
  shts.sort((a, b) => {
    let ta = a.trim().split(' ');
    let vA = new Date(ta[1], mA.indexOf(ta[0])).valueOf();
    let tb = b.trim().split(' ');
    let vB = new Date(tb[1], mA.indexOf(tb[0])).valueOf();
    return vB - vA;//This is descending vA - vB is ascending
  });//Sorting names by date values
  shts.forEach((name, i) => {
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(name));
    ss.moveActiveSheet(i + 1);
  });
}
```

If you have other sheets that do not have the same Month year format you can filter the shts list with the filter method to eliminate them.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!  The second set of code works great!  It's not quite 100% (I think that's due to the various people working on this document not always using the full month or other naming issues), but this gets me 95% of the way there.  I really appreciate it!!!!!!

Comment: The first function works well after slight modification. ForEach is referring to an undefined list.

sorted.forEach(
    (tabname,i) => {
      ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(tabname));
      ss.moveActiveSheet(i + 1);
    }
  );

Worked flawlessly for me @Cooper.